# Check the differentiability of a function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ on the boundary of unit circle.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Define the function $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ by
$$f(x,y):=\begin{cases}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} &\text{ if } x^2+y^2 \ge 1\\ 1 &\text{ if } x^2+y^2<1\end{cases}$$

Checck the differentiability of the function $f$. I know the definition of differentiability at a point $(a,b)$ of several variable function. But to check for this function, we have to check the differentiability of each point on the boundary of the unit circle.

Hopw to chech this? Any hint. please..

Answer (score 1):

If the function were differentiable, then the function would be differentiable when restricted to the $x$ axis. On this set, it is the function
$$ f(x,0) = \max(1,|x|)$$
which is patently not differentiable at $x=1$. Also, by the rotational symmetry of $f$, the function is not differentiable anywhere on the unit circle.

Alternatively (actually the same argument) verify that at each $r\in \partial B(0,1)$, the one-sided directional derivatives in the directions $\pm r$ do not agree; so it is not (Gateaux) differentiable on the unit circle.